# What is the probability to draw a black card, given draws without replacement?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability, card-games

If given a standard deck of 52 cards, what is the probability of drawing a black card on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th ... $n^{th}$ draw?

I understand that the first is $26/52$, but the second gets a bit more complicated because there is two scenarios: 
 **a)** The first draw is black so the probability is $26/52$ * $25/51$ 
**b)** The first draw is non-black, so the probability is $26/52$ * $26/51$

I'm not sure what the formulaic expression of this is and how to consider **both** of these options in one calculation. I know it uses combinatorics, but I'm lost.

Thanks!

Comment: The options in question are mutually exclusive, so you add the two probabilities you found.  The result is that the probability the second card is black is $1/2$.  This is because, absent other information, a black card is equally likely to be any position in the deck.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig How would I extend it to 3 draws, 4 draws, and so forth? I'm going to go on a limb here and say this is the law of total probability, but with three draws, this would result in an awfully long calculation, no? Because then I have to account for **4** scenarios instead of **2**, correct?

Comment: Repeat: "This is because, absent other information, a black card is equally likely to be any position in the deck."  So the probability that, say, the fifty-second card in the deck is black will be:... $1/2$.

Comment: The key idea here is that a black card is equally likely to be in any position of the deck.  Thus, the probability that, in the absence of other information, the card in the $k$th position is black is $26/52 = 1/2$ for each $k$ such that $1 \leq k \leq 52$.  Imagine laying out the cards from left to right, face down, then pointing at the $k$th card.  What is the probability it is black?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thinking about it, it makes more sense to me now. Thank you!

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I confirm this is the correct answer, but I thought about it computationally instead of logically like you have. Instead, I confirmed it by doing the total probability, indeed, it is $1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you shuffle the cards randomly, and that you are picking from the top. Then you want the probability of the first n cards being all black. There are $n! {26 \choose n}$ possible permutation of black cards being at the top. Now, you may choose any permutation for the remaining cards, so there are $(52-n)!$ choices left. Hence, the probability of getting permutation that gives us our desired situation is

$$\frac{n! {26 \choose n} (52-n)!}{52!}$$